# Construct notification from data payload

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit

I do a post request to Firebase push notifications:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
suspend fun createPushNotifications(
    @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String,
    @Field("to") to: String,
    @Field("data") data: String
): Response<ResponseBody>

    // Create Retrofit
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl(urlApp)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    // Create Service
    val service = retrofit.create(notificationAPI::class.java)

    var data:String = "{\"body\":\"value\",\"title\":\"Collapsing A\"}"

    // Do the POST request and get response
    val response = service.createPushNotifications(FireBaseKey,deviceId, data)
```

Question : I get back a wrong format data payload
Message

```
data payload:{data={"body":"value","title":"Collapsing A"}}
But what i need is a payload in this format:
{data: {"body":"value","title":"Collapsing A"}}
```